# Convergence of an uncountable sequence of functions

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence, sequence-of-function

I have a function $g(\cdot)$ such that such that $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty}g(t-s)=0$. I need to show that $\lim\limits_{T \to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^tg(T-s)ds=0$, where $0<t\ll T$.
I thought that Lebsegue dominated convergence theorem would work, because the assumption we make implies that $g(T-s)$ can be bounded by some integrable function, for big $T$. However, all convergence theorems I've found deal with countable sequences of functions, while here $T$ belongs to an uncountable set. I would be grateful for suggestions how to deal with this problem. If any additional assumptions need to be made, that's perfectly fine (I'm using this function as a part of my model, so I can play around with it).

Comment: $\lim_{t\to a}H(t)=L$ is equivalent to "For all sequences $x_n\to a$, $H(x_n)\to L$". ... Well ... the $t$ in the first limit has to be moving in a space that has a countable neighborhood basis for $a$. In your case $t$ moves on the reals. You are fine.

Comment: That actually seems to solve my problem, I knew I was trying to overcomplicate it. Thanks!